# IAR lmibrary compilation : Remove / hide internal symbols and APIs

Tags: compilation, workbench, iar

We are using IAR Embedded workbench to create Libraries.

When we compile project using these libraries, we are facing to an issue :
if application layer implements a function with same name as a function defined in a Library, 'duplicate definition' error is notified during application compilation.

In order to avoid this error type, I just want to know if there is a way to hide internal APIs and also internal symbols (global variables...) of compiled Library?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For internal functions and variables which are used only in single compilation unit, you can give them internal linkage with `static` keyword:

```
/*library.c*/
static int internalLinkageVar;
static void internalLinkageFunc(void);
```

This will of course not work for symbols which must be accessible to multiple .c files in library. For those it is best to use resonably long prefix on symbol name:

```
int MyLibrary_Private_Var2;
void MyLibrary_Private_Func(void);
```

Comment: Is there not a better way to do this than "Just give them a longer name"?
Maybe partial linking with a steering file?

Comment: @TomE I don't see obvious way to do partial linking, but my IAR version is a bit old now, and I may have missed something while skimming through the manual. I try to avoid using features which require extra work when switching compilers, so simply using longer name is often the path of least resistance.

Comment: @TomE As a workaround; Assuming you don't use both app and lib function in the same compilation unit, you could change app function to longer name, but use `#define` to make a short alias for local usage. Not elegant, but C is not perfect language to begin with.